# Gmail App is not differentiating Read and UnRead Emails in Vivo Android Mobile

Tags: gmail

In Android Gmail App, It has unread emails with bold and read emails without bold to identify which emails are unread. But in my Vivo V7 Android Mobile I couldn't able to see that differentiations and all the emails are showing without bold and hence this app is not so helpful for me.

Below are the steps I tried,

1. Cleared Cache of App.
2. Signed out and Signed in
3. Rebooting mobile
4. Tried al the settings

Nothing helped me. Please give a solution for this issue,

[image]

Comment: If I see it correctly mail 1, 3, 4, 6, 7 are bold. It is just the strange system font used on your phone that has nearly no difference between normal and bold.

Comment: I'm afraid this is the issue with the system font, not really Gmail's fault. I assume this is the default font, not your customization?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned by Robert and Andrew in comments, this issue was due to System Font, which was a custom one and not a default one. Once I changed to Default Font, I could able to see gmail is showing as normal fonts.